# Preventing re-renders of Components using useContext hook to set the Global State of the Player

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks, react-context

I am trying to implement a MiniGlobalPlayer which would be global throughout the app , and some components can set the state of the MiniGlobalPlayer.I thought React Context will be a good solution with useContext and useReducer Hook. But, re-rendering of components is making my app slow(***Lag is proportional to the number of VideoItem components mounted on the DOM using useContext(setGlobalVideo***)).

https://beebom.com/youtubes-new-ui-trick-is-a-mini-player-bar-for-collapsed-video-playback/ (MiniGlobalPlayer of Youtube)

Full Scenario:

State of the MiniGlobalPlayer is determined by onPress() on VideoItem component,
 which uses useContext hook to get the method setVideo from setGlobalVideo context which would set the state of the MiniGlobalPlayer

```
const areEqual = (prevProps, nextProps) => true
 const VideoItem= React.memo((props)=> {
   const context = useContext(setGlobalVideo)
        return ( 
          <View style={[
            styles.flex, styles.column, styles.recommendation, styles.shadow, 
            {marginLeft: theme.sizes.margin },
          ]} key ={props.index}>
          <View style={[styles.flex, styles.recommendationHeader]}>
          <TouchableOpacity  onPress={()=>{context.setGlobalVideo(props.video)}}>
          <Image style={[styles.recommendationImage]} source={ {uri: props.video.Video_Pictures["0"]}} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <ExpensiveVideoRendering index={props.index} video={props.video}/>  
          </View>
        </View>
          );

  }, areEqual);

export default VideoItem;
```

MiniGlobalPlayerProvider stores the global video state and PlayerReducer can change it's state according to the action dispatched.  The actions are dispatched by the VideoItem Components which are present in various parts of the app to set the global video state.

```
const MiniGlobalPlayerProvider=({children})=>{
  const initialState ={
    video: null, 
    isPlaying : false, 
    isBuffering: false
  }
  const [state, dispatch]= useReducer(PlayerReducer,initialState )
  const {video} =state
function togglePodcast(podcast)  {
    animation = new Value(0);
    timing(
      animation,
      {
        toValue: video ? 1 : 0,
        duration: 300,
        easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.ease),
      },
    ).start();
  };
  animation = new Value(0);
  const setVideo=(video)=>
  {
    dispatch(
      {
        type: SET_GLOBAL_VIDEO, 
        payload: video    
      }
    )
    toggleVideo(video)

  }  
    const translateY = animation.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: [height, 0],
    });
    return (
      <setGlobalVideo.Provider value={{setVideo}}>  
      <PlayerContext.Provider value={video}>


        <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}>
            {children}
          </View>
          {

            !isOS && video && <VideoPlayer {...{video}} />
          }
        </View>
      </PlayerContext.Provider>
      </setGlobalVideo.Provider>  
    );
  }
```

PlayerReducer.js

```
export default PlayerReducer=(state, action )=>
{
    switch(action.type){
        case SET_GLOBAL_VIDEO:
            return {...state, video:action.payload}
        default: {
                throw new Error(`Unhandled action type: ${action.type}`)
              }

    }
}
```

Solutions that I have tried to reduce the un-necessary re-renders :
1.Any Component using useContext is re-rendered when the Provider state is changed. So, Expensive Computation is passed to an inner component which is not re-rendered by using **React.memo()**.
2. **use useCallback (** Pass an inline callback and an array of dependencies. useCallback will return a memoized version of the callback that only changes if one of the dependencies has changed. This is useful when passing callbacks to optimized child components that rely on reference equality to prevent unnecessary renders (e.g. shouldComponentUpdate).)

```
const setVideo=useCallback((video)=>
      {
        dispatch(
          {
            type: SET_GLOBAL_VIDEO, 
            payload: video    
          }
        )
        toggleVideo(video)

      }  )
```

3. Seperate Contexts (  setGlobalVideo.Provider,
     PlayerContext.Provider )
4. https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-prevent-rerender-component
   5.https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15156
   6.https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14110

I have still not been able to stop these re-renders. Can anyone help me with this?